# Azure stream analytics doesn't receive Iot Hub events when a route created

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-iot-hub, azure-stream-analytics

We are using a Stream Analytics Job to transfer some data to CosmosDB(DocumentDB ). And we want to create some routes in IOT Hub (to Service Bus, Notification Hub vs.) When we create it. Routed messages doesnt receieve to Stream analytic job(which uses $Default Consumer Group)  we want this data written to DocumentDB as well. Is it possible to do this? 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following route in the Azure IoT Hub Routes:

[image: routes]